# Is there a possibility to replicate a folder or a network share to a SharePoint site/documents/library?

Tags: replication

My situation:

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I have a network share with lots of files but i want it to replicate with a SharePoint library. so the clients can see the files on the network share and in SharePoint itself.

is this possible? or is there another solution?

Comment: you may opt to move your files into SharePoint (if you have large files, your SharePoint Database will increase a lot); then you can make [Map Network Drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-10-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d) using the http address of site.

Answer (score 0):

This will get to be a muddy solution. Your best bet is to use one as the source and have the other 'spoof' it.

I would propose loading it all up in SharePoint, and then attach to the library as a network drive.

If you wanted to keep it all on the network drive, you could use a 3rd party solution to browse it in SP, or crawl it with search and customize a search web part.

If you reaaalllyy want a sync scenario, you might be able to use SkyDrive Pro, which treats libraries like DropBox does. You'll need a computer always running to monitor and handle the sync.

HTH

Comment: Its not necessary to keep all files. I could just move the files actually and place them to another drive or place them back. But how will i load it all in SharePoint and attach it to a library as a network drive? Can you hand me out the steps! Thankyou!

Comment: When you browse to a library in SharePoint, the ribbon has an option to Open with Explorer option: http://screencast.com/t/OkUOXcCzQQ2. Click that and it should open in Windows Explorer. From there you can drag in your files, and also map a drive to it by going to Tools > Map Network Drive in the window.

Comment: On more thing, the Open with Explorer option is only available for IE.